# Does TempleOS 5.03 ship with After Egypt and other utilities?

Tags: distribution, templeos

I've seen a [few videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz3Z5wsZrn4) where [Terry runs "After Egypt"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ETqBJZudpw) (the TempleOS utility, not the game). I don't see that in my version of Temple OS.

Was "After Egypt" removed from core Temple OS? Where are all the base utilities Terry uses in his videos (they are distributed as source code)? One of the most notable references of [TempleOS here](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/wnj43x/gods-lonely-programmer) explicitly mentions "After Egypt" as being "within" (shipped with) the operating system.

It seems I'm missing a lot of these, of which "After Egypt" is the most notable. I would like to use these utilities as examples of Temple OS functionality, both as operating system capabilities and code-examples by the creator of the system, compiler, and tool chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the supplemental utilities are now on a special ISO and not a part of the distribution. As [Alec Murphy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9760788/alec-murphy) points out, the supplemental discs can be found at the [TempleOS Download site](http://www.templeos.org/Downloads)

AfterEgypt can be found on [`TOS_Supplemental1.ISO.C`](http://www.templeos.org/Downloads/TOS_Supplemental1.ISO.C)

### Archive.org Copy

**You can [find these on archive.org if the site is down](https://web.archive.org/web/20170508204519/http://www.templeos.org:80/Wb/Home/Web/AppStore/TerryVMware.html#l1)**